# add users to og group via vbo doesn't work: record is deleted immediately

Tags: organic-groups, views

I like to add users to an [OG group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) using [vbo](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), a custom action and [og_group()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/function/og_group/7).

I build up a page with a [view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) of users to add (/node/%nid/add_user).

On this view I added a views bulk operations field with the "skip batch" option. (I skipped the batch to get the current %nid from the url).

In the custom code I like to add the selected user to the page shown. I know I can do this also with the standard group forms, but I want to do it this way :-)

So here is my code to subscribe the user to the group:

```
function mymodule_vbo_actions_users_woform(&$user_node, $context) {
  global $user;
  //dpm($node); dpm($context);return;
  switch ($context['settings']['action_type']) {
    case 'add_user_to_group':
      $nid_page = menu_get_object();
      if (!isset($nid_page)) $nid_page = arg(1);
      $nid_page = $context['page_nid'];
      $account = user_load($user_node->uid);
      //dpm($nid_page);
      $node_page = node_load($nid_page);
      dpm($user_node);
      dpm($account);
      dpm($node_page);

      $aValues = array('entity_type'=>'user','entity'=>$account,'membership type' => 'OG_MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_DEFAULT',);
      $og_membership = og_group('node',$node_page->nid,$aValues,FALSE);
      $og_membership->save();
      dpm($og_membership);

      // get member roles id for selected group bundle
      $result_roles = db_query("SELECT rid FROM og_role o where group_bundle = :bundle and name=:name and gid=:gid;",array(':bundle'=>$node_page->type,':name'=>'bidder', ':gid'=>$node_page->nid));
      $role_id = NULL;
      foreach ($result_roles as $key_roles => $value_roles) {
        $role_id = $value_roles->rid;
        break;
      }
      dpm($role_id);
      og_role_grant('node',$node_page->nid,$account->uid,$role_id);
      break;
  }
}
```

This code seems to be correct. I watched the `og_membership` table and the record for the selected user is inserted, but then DELETED immediately!?

So the question is of course: Why is the record deleted?

Comment: I found out, that if I call the `mymodule_vbo_actions_users_woform`function from another hook, e.g. a hook_node_view, the user is added to the group and is NOT deleted... So VBO deletes the record.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to grant a OG role to the new member after adding them.

e.g. `og_role_grant('node', $node_page->nid, $account->uid, 2);`

The magic number on the end determines the type of role granted. 1 = non-member, 2 = member, 3 = administrator member

Comment: May the magic number be the rid of the table og_role, where the gid = the id of the group the user should be added to and where the name=the name of the role the user should get? So my query for the rid looks like this: 

`$result_roles = db_query("SELECT rid FROM og_role o where group_bundle = :bundle and name=:name and gid=:gid;",array(':bundle'=>$group_node->type,':name'=>'editor', ':gid'=>$group_node->nid));`

I granted the role like this:
`og_role_grant('node',$group_node->nid,$account->uid,$role_id);`

Bute the result is the same, the user is not added... Although the logged in user is..

Comment: ...the admin for the group.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.

VBO is reverting the action if you don't have the proper og_permission.
So check if you have assigned the proper permissions.